# Pip and Python disagree on module location

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

OK, this is just strange. I am helping a colleague on a Mac (Yosemite), running the shipped Python executable in `/usr/bin/python` (2.7.10). I used the shipped `easy_install` to install `pip` (9.0.1), which was deposited in `/usr/local/bin` with a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/python`. I then used `pip` to install some modules, including `six`, only to find out that pip and python somehow disagree about that module's version:

Tail of `pip install -vvv -U six`:

```
Installed version (1.10.0) is most up-to-date (past versions: 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Output of `python -c 'import six; print six.__version__'`:

```
1.4.1
```

Relevant locations:

```
$ type pip
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
$ head -n 1 $(type -p pip)
#!/usr/bin/python
```

`$PYTHONPATH` is not set in the environment. But they are still looking in different places. As you can see from the `pip` output, it's looking/storing in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. But if I loop over `sys.path`, the first place I find `six` is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`.

So where's the disconnect?

Comment: Are your colleague's Mac on El Capitan ? maybe related to [this](https://github.com/FindHotel/s3keyring/issues/6)

Comment: He's running Yosemite, but it looks like a similar situation

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165#issuecomment-146666737) may help maybe

Comment: can you run this ? `python -c 'import six; print six.__file__'`

Comment: as I said in my question, `import` finding `six` in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be the order of the load path. On my Sierra machine (where I verified that I was able to install a new `six` for the default `/usr/bin/python`), `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` comes *before* `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` in `sys.path`. But on the coworker's machine, `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` is the very last entry, coming after the `Extras` folder, so the `pip`-installed version is masked by the system install.

I suspect this is a problem with the Yosemite Python installation that was fixed by Sierra, but in any case I can see no easy fix. So the options are to install a separate Python instance (my preference; I usually use `pyenv` anyway) or manually set `PYTHONPATH` to put `site-packages` out front. Or upgrade to a newer macOS, I suppose.

Thanks to everyone for the help figuring this out.